# Flutter Doctor doesn't recognized the flutter and dart plugin even after they are installed

Tags: android, flutter, plugins

I have installed the Flutter and Dart plugins in android studio but flutter doctor doesn't recognize it at all. Plus, I am running my flutter project and the emulator from VS code and it works perfectly. It even works from the android studio as well but the error messages doesn't seems to go away.

[Error in Command Prompt after running Flutter Doctor(Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmvsd.jpg)

But after creating new project from command prompt everything seems to be fine as shown in the picture above but running the flutter doctor results the same problem again!

I have already uninstalled the plugins restarted the android studio and again installed the plugins and restarted the android studio.
Already done this process a number of times.

All the path have been defined in the Environment Variable of the system variables.

Already tried running this command flutter config --android-sdk PATH_TO_ANDROID_SDK in my terminal.

These error occurred after updating Android Studio to 4.1 v from 3.5 v

I can't seem to find any solution as this error is haunting me.
*Thank you in advance.*

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem check: https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/4523

If you are on Mac:

```
 ln -s ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio4.1
```

For windows and/or Linux you can try Flutter Dev channel:

```
flutter channel beta
flutter upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

my advice for you is to uninstall the Android Studio completely, then downgrade the version. I had the same error, it started working after downgrading to Android Studio 4.0.2

Comment: Tried that many times and wasted many days still I am facing the same problem even after downgrading